# What is required for Single Log Out with Okta using ITFoxtec.Identity.Saml2?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have SSO set up and working in my app, but am trying to get SLO to function. What is required to implement SLO in an app? I have it set up in my IdP.

Here is the configuration from my Program.cs file. Am I missing anything here? Do we need any other set up in order for SLO to function correctly? Using this set up, the IdP tries to initiate a single logout when we use the logout controller action, but it does not actually sign us out of the IdP (Okta in our case).

```
builder.Services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Saml2"));

builder.Services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(saml2Configuration =>
{

    saml2Configuration.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(saml2Configuration.Issuer);

    var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
    entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromFile(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Saml2")["IDPMetadataFile"]);

    if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null)
    {
        saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
        saml2Configuration.SingleLogoutDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleLogoutServices.First().Location;
        saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);

        foreach (var signingCertificate in entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates)
        {
            if (signingCertificate.IsValidLocalTime())
            {
                saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.Add(signingCertificate);
            }
        }
        if (saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("The IdP signing certificates has expired.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to [configure Okta](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/single-logout/saml2/main/#configure-slo) to do logout and single logout.

[image]

Select `SLO initiation`.

The `Response URL` should be: https://localhost:xxxx/Auth/LoggedOut`
It is used if logout is initiated by the RP (RP-initiated logout)

Select `SLO participation` to enable IdP-initiated logout.

The `Request URL` should be: https://localhost:xxxx/Auth/SingleLogout`
It is used if logout is initiated by the IdP (IdP-initiated logout)

Use `HTTP POST` in logout request.

Select `Include user session details`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sadly SLO is still not working. Even with this setup, when I try to initiate a single log out, it does not log me out of the IdP.

Comment: Do we need a signature certificate in order to sign the SLO request? Is that the .pfx file in the sample?

Comment: If the app (RP) start logout with a logout request to the IdP the app need to sign with the .pfx cert in the sample. If the IdP start SLO with a logout request it sign the request with the IdP cert.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to figure it out. We needed a .pem and .pfx pair... uploaded the .pem to the "Signature Certificate" field in Okta settings, and used the .pfx file inside of the app in order to sign the request. The SP Issuer also had to match the Audience URI (SP Entity ID) in the General settings in Okta as well. Hope this manages to help other people.